# A static class constants to act like string enums issue when its being called

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have searched everywhere but cannot find a solution, so I am asking the question here. I have a procedure which  takes a parameter  of a string enum type (which has been created in a static class), but I keep getting string cannot be converted to mytype. Which i find odd as I am actually sending it one of its type. Can someone please help me understand what I am missing. I understand the error but I do not get it as I am passing through its type.

Below is the static class type created in c#

```
public static class ExportedType
{
    public const string CSV = "csv";
    public const string XML = "xml";
}
```

I create a procedure in vb.net

```
Private Sub ExportData(exportedType As ExportedType)
   'stuff in here
End Sub
```

I try to call it

```
ExportData(ExportedType.XML)
```

and i keep getting value type string cannot be converted to ExportedType

My guess is I am missing something vital, but can some try to explain for me.

Thanks

Comment: The link to the duplicate question is at the top of the post.

Answer (score 0):

`ExportedType.XML` is of type `string` - not of type `ExportedType` as your method signature expects.

Strings are strings, enums are enums. If you want an enum, define `ExportedType` as an enum.

So either define your method like this

```
Private Sub ExportData(exportedType As String)
   'stuff in here
End Sub
```

or keep your method as-is and define your enum like this:

```
public enum ExportedType
{
    CSV,
    XML
}
```

It is fairly common to markup enum values with a `DescriptionAttribute` to provide a string representation:

```
public enum ExportedType
{
    [Description("csv")]
    CSV,
    [Description("xml")]
    XML
}
```

These can be read quite easily using reflection

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToDescriptionString(this ExportedType val)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])val
           .GetType()
           .GetField(val.ToString())
           .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally i wanted an enum, but with strings

Comment: @altaaf.hussein how about the edit with `DescriptionAttribute`? Or look at canton7's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ExportedType.CSV` is a `string` - you declared it as a string with `public const string CSV`. It's not an instance of `ExportedType`, and therefore you cannot pass it to a method which expects a parameter of type `ExportedType`.

One option is to make your `ExportData` method take a `string` instead of an `ExportedData`. Then you can pass `ExportedData.CSV` (which evaluates to the string `"CSV"`):

Another option is to use a normal enum, and forget about strings:

```
public enum ExportedData { CSV, XML }
```

The third option, and I think this is what you were going for, is to create a "Java-style" enum. This gives you some of the best of both worlds: it's obvious to callers of `ExportData` that they need to pass a member of `ExportedType` (and not any old string), but it also lets you get a string value out of each member of `ExportedType`.

To do this, your `ExportedData` class needs to have static members which are of type `ExportedData`, not `string`:

```
public class ExportedType
{
    public string Value { get; }
    private ExportedType(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static readonly ExportedType CSV = new ExportedType("CSV");
    public static readonly ExportedType XML = new ExportedType("XML");
}
```

Then you can pass `ExportedType.CSV` as an `ExportedType` instance, and access `exportedType.Value` to get the string `"CSV"`.

Answer (score 0):

`CSV` and `XML` are (string) properties of the `ExportedType` class, and not instances of it. At the very least, this: `Private Sub ExportData(exportedType As ExportedType)` needs to be changed to `Private Sub ExportData(exportedType As String)`.